# Do I need a license to embed Helvetica or Coolvetica into an app?

Tags: font-licensing, embed

What are the terms of embedding Helvetica into a mobile application? Is it different than web-based embedding?

How about another one? Coolvetica? The 1990s spin-off? Pretty sure they aren't owned by the same corporations...

Anyways, what penalties will one face if either are found in use in your mobile application? Do you need a specific license? If so, where can one find it?

Answer (score 4):

You need a license from Linotype (for either Helvetica or Coolvetica)

Yes there is a specific "App" license, see:

https://www.linotype.com/1308886/helvetica-family.html

I can't say what the penalties are, but you will at bare minimum be forced to buy the appropriate license.